# Ambiguity between event and filed name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is possible to have a property and a event with the same name in a class for example:

```
private BusyChangedDelegate BusyChanged;

public event BusyChangedDelegate BusyChanged
{
.
.
.
}
```

**Edit**
Complete source

```
 private BusyChangedDelegate BusyChanged;
        public event BusyChangedDelegate BusyChanged
        {
            add
            {
                BusyChangedDelegate delegate3;
                BusyChangedDelegate busyChanged = this.BusyChanged;
                do
                {
                    delegate3 = busyChanged;
                    BusyChangedDelegate delegate4 = (BusyChangedDelegate) Delegate.Combine(delegate3, value);
                    busyChanged = Interlocked.CompareExchange<BusyChangedDelegate>(ref this.BusyChanged, delegate4, delegate3);
                }
                while (busyChanged != delegate3);
            }
            remove
            {
                BusyChangedDelegate delegate3;
                BusyChangedDelegate busyChanged = this.BusyChanged;
                do
                {
                    delegate3 = busyChanged;
                    BusyChangedDelegate delegate4 = (BusyChangedDelegate) Delegate.Remove(delegate3, value);
                    busyChanged = Interlocked.CompareExchange<BusyChangedDelegate>(ref this.BusyChanged, delegate4, delegate3);
                }
                while (busyChanged != delegate3);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A class can't declare two members with the same name, other than for method overloading.

Just change your variable name to be camelCased, which follows the normal conventions anyway...

```
private BusyChangedDelegate busyChanged;
```

From section 10.3 of the C# 5 specification:

> The name of a constant, field, property, event, or type must differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

EDIT: Yes, if you look at the IL generated for a field-like event:

```
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

you *may* see both a field called `Foo` and an event called `Foo`. That's because IL has different rules to C#. The C# compiler can name the auto-generated field however it wants. (See section 10.8.1 of the C# 4 specification, for example.)

It's still not valid *in the C# language* to name a field the same way as any other member. The code you have posted is not valid C# - it's the best a decompiler can come up with to represent what the C# compiler has created in IL.

Comment: Regarding normal conventions, it's important to note that he used a *field* in his example (not a property), which is why the suggestion to change the name to `busyChanged` is a correct convention.

Comment: @Jon Skeet :I open a application source with  .net reflector some event and filed have the same name,i want to ask why this happen?

Comment: @irsog: Are you sure those weren't the *implementation* parts of the event? (Try doing the same with an event that you declare yourself.)

Comment: @irsog: Ah, you've changed "property" to "field" in your comment. That makes an enormous difference. Basically this is because the C# compiler is able to generate two members with the same name - but it's not actually valid C#.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:so,having a filed and a event with same name in a class is possible?

Comment: @irsog: It's possible in IL. It's not possible in C#. See my edit.